# Playing the same mp3 file again using NAudio

Tags: .net, naudio

what is the recommended way to play an mp3 file over and over again using NAudio?

what I do so far:

in one global place:

```
Mp3Reader mp3Reader = new Mp3FileReader(url);
```

then for each time the mp3 should be played:

```
WaveStream channel = new WaveChannel32( mp3Reader) ;
IWavePlayer waveout = new WaveOut();
waveout.Init(channel);
waveout.PlaybackStopped += new EventHandler(naudio_PlaybackStopped);
waveout.Play();
```

but it only plays the first time.

furthermore it gives this assertion:

```
WaveOut device was not closed
```

it's possible that the mp3 file should be played again while the first instance is still playing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to loop back to back, I would do this by creating a custom `IWaveProvider`, which internally creates an `Mp3FileReader`. Then in the `Read` method, it passes through the data it reads from the `Mp3FileReader`. When it gets to the end (`mp3FileReader.Read` returns 0), you set the Position back to 0 and carry on reading (and you could insert a bit of silence in between too).

Another approach is to use the `MixingSampleProvider` in the latest version of NAudio ([available on Nuget](https://nuget.org/packages/NAudio/1.5)) which you could then just add instances of `AudioFileReader` to whenever you wanted to play back your MP3 file. Then you could actually have the same MP3 file playing at the same time. You might also want to put a dummy never-ending silence stream in as well to ensure playback never ends and you can queue up a new MP3 at any time.

Also, "WaveOut device was not closed" means exactly that. You can't call Init a second time. You must Dispose your original and create a new one (e.g. in your PlaybackStopped handler) if you don't want to go with the custom wave provider or mixer approach.

Comment: thanks for the answer. i will try the second option and let you know if it works. this is for a game, btw.

Comment: about the waveoutdevice error: i actually do Dispose() the WaveOut int the playbackstopped. as you can see in my sample code i create a new WaveOut for every time the mp3 should be played.

Comment: OK, may be a driver issue. Usually you can create multiple instances of WaveOut for the same soundcard.

Comment: aha. could that also be the problem why ASIO is not working? it says i dont have an ASIO driver installed.